# Error: pg_config executable not found in Gitlab Runner

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to setup gitlab ci pipeline, but the build task always failed because psycopg2-binary.

I did some googling and found that switch between 2.7.x and 2.8.x will be fine, but not luck for me.

However, docker-compose working fine when building on local machine.

Anyone please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use python:3.7 as image, that worked for me